# Unable to get the updated text of text box

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've one text box and one update button:

**Text box:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**update button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdFName" runat="server"Text="Update" onclick="btnUpdFName_Click"/>
```

What I am doing in page load event I am getting the **first name from database and assinging it to text box** as follows:

```
txtFName.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Now when i earases the text set at page load event in text box as above and write another name and press update button, i am trying to get the new text entered in the text box in the button click event as follows:

```
string FName = txtFName.Text;
```

But the problem is that every time I write new text in text box, I am still **getting the same text as set form database** (dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()).
I am not able to get the current text from the text box and getting only the intial value set from db in page load event.

What I encountered that after compilation my text box markup becomes as follows:

```
<input id="CPHcontent_txtFName" type="text" value="value set from db i.e. dt.Rows[0] [1].ToString()" name="ctl00$CPHcontent$txttxtFName"></input>
```

the text box alway has the same value set from the db. Thats why i am getting each time the same value regardless of value entered by user in text box.

Now tell me how to get the updated value of text box in my page behind.

Thanx in advance

Comment: show your page load event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net webforms you should separate code for setting data to control and for saving data to db. One of ways to set data to control - use check

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    txtFName.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
}
```

in page load event.
Otherwise you will overwrite your newly entered text for textbox on every page load.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably overwriting the text you entered in your Page Load event, because you are not checking if it is a PostBack.
Please read [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further information.

Comment: ya you are write... I forgot to bind text in if not post back... now i m able to get the text.. thax alot.

Answer (score 0):

Set the textbox  to empty or null before you try to set/read it again onpageload.